# Getting data from a server to a HTML mobile application

Tags: cordova, mobile, amazon-ec2, server

I want to create an application where users can upload text/pictures using a website, and then on a mobile app (written in html) be able to pull that information into the app and display it. Sort of like on a facebook feed, or twitter feed.

On the server side, what would I need? I know Node.js, and looked into Amazon EC2 servers, but I'm not sure that's what I need. I basically need a server that holds a load of information and sends back the relevant information to be displayed in the app. Would I just need a server with a MySQL database on that holds all the information, and returns information based on queries sent by the app?

What should I be looking at doing?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a frontend for some user action, I would prefer MySQL and some script language like PHP.

The best way to interact between the cordova app and your frontend is for the data part JSON. It's very easy to use.

The images you can download to the devices by [the org.apache.cordova.file-transfer](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file-transfer) plugin. It does all the important things and is cross platform compatible.

**UPDATE:**

The MySQL server holds the image infos, like filename, size(?), compression(?) … and the images you put as raw files on the server.

If you have low traffic you could use a virtual machine, where the web server and the database server are running on the same machine. It's the standard for most providers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I don't understand where the actual MySQL server would be though. Just on a virtual server machine?

Comment: Thank you! So using an amazon EC2 server with a MySQL database on should do the trick I think :)?